# error in using insert query in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am saving some data and pic to my db I found out the true way to save my pic in db is to use contentvalue so this the code:

```
                try 
                {

                    MyDataBase = new MyDatabase(this);
                    mydb = MyDataBase.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues tempval;
                    for (int j = 0; j < myarray.arrtitle.length; j++)
                    {
                        tempval = saveimage(myarray.arrpic.get(j),myarray.arrpath[j]);
                        mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO news (title,content) VALUES  (\"" + myarray.arrtitle[j] +
                        "\",\"" + myarray.arrcontent[j] + "\"" + ")");
                        mydb.insert("news", null, tempval);
                    }
                    mydb.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "database 2 done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    count = 5;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: daabase error2
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data error2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

so this is how i can save my data correctly.
but the problem is when I insert my image, it insert in new row not the row as same as title was inserted.
is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use UPDATE query, if you want to edit some column data of an already existing row. Every time you execute INSERT query, it will create a new row.

You are executing INSERT query twice, once you are inserting title and content and then in next query you are inserting image path. Instead while saving image path you should execute UPDATE query for the same row in which you saved corresponding data.

Use LIKE instead of = operator.

```
// updating row 
db.update(TABLE, tempval , "title LIKE ?", new String[] { myarray.arrtitle[j] })
```

Comment: thank you. so i have to use this : mydb.update("news", tempval, "where _id =" + j + '"' , null);

Comment: thank you. whould you mind giving me hand for my update query. It doesnt work.

Comment: this is the code:                                                                                      for (int j = 0; j < myarray.arrtitle.length; j++)
      {
       tempval = saveimage(myarray.arrpic.get(j),myarray.arrpath[j]);
       update ='"' +  "where title ='" + myarray.arrtitle[j] + "'" + '"' ;
       
       mydb.update("news", tempval,update, null);
       
      }

Comment: Use LIKE instead of = operator.

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE, tempval ,  "title LIKE ?",
                new String[] { myarray.arrtitle[j] });